# Azure Container Instance (Windows Container) web application accessible to specific network (Intranet application setup)

Tags: azure, docker, containers

Is it possible to have an intranet application setup using ACI's Windows container?
There is a network in the office and workstations connected to network must be restricted to access web application hosted using ACI's.
I don't see VNet's enabled for Windows Container in ACI.
Do we have any workarounds to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

ACI Windows containers cannot be vNet joined currently. I'd recommend looking at Web Apps, which can be vNet joind and support private endpoints.

Comment: Was waiting for your answer sir :) I dare not to use webapps for windows container due to still in preview. Has Microsoft suggest any work around to use ACI for intranet web application use cases?

Comment: BTW, please keep updating your article on windows container and azure. I will constantly glaze through your article for any updates :)

Comment: I'm not suggesting you use Webapps for containers, just plain old Windows web apps. There is no currently a Windows Container solution that will support vNet joining except for AKS, running with Windows nodes.